# django-rest-auth: Issue with Password Reset functionaliity

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I have been trying to setup password reset functionality in DRF using [django-rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth). Earlier I was getting error **TemplateDoesNotExist:registration/password_reset_email.html** which I resolved by adding the following code

***serializer.py***

```
from rest_auth.serializers import PasswordResetSerializer
from allauth.account.forms import ResetPasswordForm  

class PasswordSerializer(PasswordResetSerializer):
    password_reset_form_class = ResetPasswordForm
```

***settings.py***

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'PASSWORD_RESET_SERIALIZER': 'api.serializers.PasswordSerializer',
}
```

However, Now I am getting into another issue - ***"NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'account_reset_password_from_key' not found. 'account_reset_password_from_key' is not a valid view function or pattern name."***. And haven't found any solution or workaround for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you added the URLs as noted in step 3 on http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installation ? If so have you name spaced the URLs?

Comment: Yeah! I had added the mentioned URLs. The password reset flow seemed complex to me. However, after going through the code and debugging a lot I found the problem and now its working. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Using your serializer.py and settings.py above, I get this error: /rest_auth/utils.py", line 10, in import_callable
    package, attr = path_or_callable.rsplit('.', 1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
. Any idea what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, finally I got the password reset functionality working. Here is how it goes -

We just need one URL in our ***urls.py*** -

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^account/', include('allauth.urls')),  
url(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),  

# This is the only URL required for BASIC password reset functionality.
# This URL creates the confirmation link which is sent via e-mail. All of the rest
# password reset features get their reverse lookup via django-allauth and django-rest-auth.
url(r'^password-reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', TemplateView.as_view(),  name='password_reset_confirm'), 

url(r'^rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', allauthemailconfirmation,
    name="account_confirm_email"),
url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls'), name='account_signup'),  
]
```

Using this URL configuration raised ***TemplateDoesNotExist at /api/rest-auth/password/reset/*** error first. After a lot of debugging, I found that the issue was raised for the template -  ***registration/password_reset_email.html*** which resides under the Django Admin's template directory. This happened due to another Django app that I was using and it had disabled the django admin app.

So, adding ***'django.contrib.admin'*** under *INSTALLED_APPS* and removing the serializers resolved the issue.

I hope this resolves issue for others as well.

***PS:*** Debugger is your best friend. ;)